# Validation extensions

Tags: c#, validation, extension-methods, framework, expression-trees

I've been working on another timesaver because I really really don't like to type all those validation `if`s and exceptions over an over again.

What I came up with this time is a set of validation extensions that make use of expression trees even if very simple ones.

---

There are three classes. The basis is the `Validate` class that creates the first validation context:

```
public static class Validate
{
    public static ValidationContext<TArg> Expression<TArg>(Expression<Func<TArg>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        var value = expression.Compile()();
        return new ValidationContext<TArg>()
        {
            Argument = value,
            Name = name
        };
    }
}
```

Then a `ValidationContext` passes the information about the expression and its value:

```
public class ValidationContext<TArg>
{
    public TArg Argument { get; internal set; }

    public string Name { get; internal set; }
}
```

Finally there are all the validation extensions (I removed some of them to make the list shorter):

```
public static class Validation
{
    public static ValidationContext<TArg> IsNotNull<TArg>(this ValidationContext<TArg> context)
    {
        if (context.Argument == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(context.Name);
        return context;
    }

    public static ValidationContext<string> IsNotNullOrEmpty(this ValidationContext<string> context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Argument)) throw new ArgumentNullException(context.Name);
        return context;
    }

    public static ValidationContext<TArg> IsLessThen<TArg>(this ValidationContext<TArg> context, TArg max) where TArg : IComparable
    {
        if (!(context.Argument.CompareTo(max) < 0))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(context.Name, $"'{context.Name}' of '{context.Argument}' is not less then '{max}'.");
        return context;
    }

    public static ValidationContext<TArg> IsLessThenOrEqual<TArg>(this ValidationContext<TArg> context, TArg max) where TArg : IComparable
    {
        if (!(context.Argument.CompareTo(max) <= 0))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(context.Name, $"'{context.Name}' of '{context.Argument}' is not less then or eqal '{max}'.");
        return context;
    }

    public static ValidationContext<TArg> IsBetween<TArg>(this ValidationContext<TArg> context, TArg min, TArg max) where TArg : IComparable
    {
        if (!(context.Argument.CompareTo(min) > 0 && context.Argument.CompareTo(max) < 0))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(context.Name, $"'{context.Name}' of '{context.Argument}' is not between '{min}' and {max}.");
        return context;
    }

    public static ValidationContext<TArg> IsBetweenOrEqual<TArg>(this ValidationContext<TArg> context, TArg min, TArg max) where TArg : IComparable
    {
        if (!(context.Argument.CompareTo(min) >= 0 && context.Argument.CompareTo(max) <= 0))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(context.Name, $"'{context.Name}' of '{context.Argument}' is not between or equal '{min}' and {max}.");
        return context;
    }   

    public static ValidationContext<TArg> IsEqual<TArg>(this ValidationContext<TArg> context, TArg value) where TArg : IComparable
    {
        if (context.Argument.CompareTo(value) != 0) throw new Exception($"'{context.Name}' is not equal '{value.ToString()}'.");
        return context;
    }

    public static ValidationContext<TArg> Where<TArg>(this ValidationContext<TArg> context, Func<TArg, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (!predicate(context.Argument)) throw new Exception($"'{context.Name}' is not valid.");
        return context;
    }

    public static ValidationContext<string> IsMatch(this ValidationContext<string> context, string pattern, RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None)
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(context.Argument, pattern, options)) throw new Exception($"'{context.Name}' does not match '{pattern}'.");
        return context;
    }

    public static ValidationContext<TArg2> And<TArg, TArg2>(this ValidationContext<TArg> context, Expression<Func<TArg, TArg2>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        var value = expression.Compile()(context.Argument);
        return new ValidationContext<TArg2>()
        {
            Argument = value,
            Name = name
        };
    }
}
```

The last extension in this class allows to chain another expression and more validations.

Here are some examples (the lines throwing exceptions are commented out):

```
var foo = (string)null;

//Validate.Expression(() => foo).IsNotNull(); // bam!
//Validate.Expression(() => foo).IsNotNullOrEmpty(); // bam!

foo = "bar";

Validate.Expression(() => foo).IsNotNull().IsMatch("[a-z]+");
//Validate.Expression(() => foo).IsNotNull().Matches("^[a-z]{2}$"); // bam!

Validate.Expression(() => foo.Length).IsEqual(3);
//Validate.Expression(() => foo.Length).IsEqual(4); // bam!

// chaining more expressions
Validate.Expression(() => foo).IsNotNull().And(s => s.Length).IsEqual(3);
//Validate.Expression(() => foo).IsNotNull().And(s => s.Length).IsEqual(4); // bam!

Validate.Expression(() => foo.Length).IsBetween(2, 4);
//Validate.Expression(() => foo.Length).IsBetween(3, 4);

Validate.Expression(() => foo.Length).IsBetweenOrEqual(3, 6);
//Validate.Expression(() => foo.Length).IsBetweenOrEqual(4, 6); // bam!

var baz = 3;

Validate.Expression(() => baz).IsLessThen(4);
Validate.Expression(() => baz).IsLessThenOrEqual(3);
//Validate.Expression(() => baz).IsLessThenOrEqual(2); // bam!
```

You can also return the final value:

```
var length = Validate.Expression(() => foo.Length).IsBetween(2, 4).Argument;
```

---

The main goals are:

- easy to use
- easy to extend
- provide as much information as possible
- simplify validation

Comment: Expressions are slow, really slow, and there is no syntactically easy way to cache the compiled one. There are though some [libraries](https://github.com/danielwertheim/ensure.that/wiki) which allow to use them for validations.

Comment: @DmitryNogin Oh! Great, I see I've reinvented the wheel ;-] About the performance... damn! They give us such cool possibilities only to make them slow :(

Comment: Under those circumstances I find there is no need for the `class.method(expr).extension()` syntax. I'll use extensions only.

Comment: @NikitaB this is v1 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time I'm going to write my own review ;-)

For most of you this isn't a great discovery but compiling an expression is a real performance hit. For 10k loops it makes a difference of at least 3sec on my machine.

I refactored my code and implemented a few optimizations. They are not very pretty but at least the difference between the expression and expression-less version is about 4milliseconds for 10k loops so actually negligible.

The new `Validate` class:

```
public static class Validate
{
    public static ValidationContext<TArg> Expression<TArg>(
        Func<TArg> lambda, 
        Func<Expression<Func<TArg>>> memberExpression)
    {
        return new ValidationContext<TArg>()
        {
            Argument = lambda(),
            Expression = memberExpression
        };
    }

    public static ValidationContext<TArg> Expression<TArg>(
        Func<TArg> lambda, 
        string memberName)
    {
        return new ValidationContext<TArg>()
        {
            Argument = lambda(),
            MemberName = memberName
        };
    }    
}
```

The updated context:

```
public class ValidationContext<TArg>
{
    private string _memberName;

    public TArg Argument { get; internal set; }

    public string MemberName
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_memberName)) return _memberName;
            var memberExpression = Expression().Body as MemberExpression;
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }
        set { _memberName = value; }
    }

    internal Func<Expression<Func<TArg>>> Expression { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I either can specify the member name or evaluate it dynamicaly. I do it only in case of an exception. The `Func<Expression<Func<TArg>>>` prevents the expression to be build prematurely.

It's call probably wouldn't win a beauty competition but what else we can do:

```
var foo = "bar";
Validate.Expression(() => foo, () => () => foo).IsNotNullOrEmpty();
```

So after all it's not that bad, isn't it? ;-)